# How to discover the machine location with Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, location

Windows has this feature where you can set the (physical) location of your machine.

Say you bought your computer in England and then moved to the United States. You can then go to "Region and Language" and change your location to match the physical one.

[image: User Location]

In a project I'm currently working on, there is the need of using this feature to show some different content.

First we tried using [QLocale::country()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocale.html#country) for such. But then we realized that this method was fetching the information from the format (image below) rather than from the location.

[image: User format]

Using Windows API's [GetUserGeoID()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318138%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) we were able to achieve it. But since this application will be ported to Linux in the near future, I want to know: Is it possible to fetch this information using Qt only?

Comment: `Windows has this feature... this application will be ported to Linux in the near future...` and Linux hasn´t this feature. Language and keyboard layout yes, but no distinct global location setting.

Comment: Maybe http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimezone.html#country

Comment: @Skhaz As your link says, this is about time zones and their usual contries. Not about a location setting independent from the time (and/or language and/or keyboard)

Comment: If you want to make this feature crossplatform add this setting to your application - so user can choose his lcoation

Comment: Yes, @Skhaz link is related to the timezone, not on the country setting. Add this option in a settings screen inside the software is an idea to make it portable. Thank you guys. :)